# Running another program but leaving stdout/stderr alone

Tags: java, processbuilder

I need, from a Java program, to run another program (a plain commandline executable), wait for it to finish, check the exit code. This can be done easily enough:

```
static void run(String[] cmd) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
  var more = false;
  for (var s : cmd) {
    if (more) System.out.print(' ');
    more = true;
    System.out.print(s);
  }
  System.out.println();
  var builder = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
  var process = builder.start();
  process.waitFor();
  var e = process.exitValue();
  if (e != 0) {
    System.out.println("process exit value: " + e);
    System.exit(e);
  }
}
```

However, stdout/stderr from that program, go into the bit bucket. Is there a way to change things so that stdout/stderr appear on the console as normal, the way they would if the program was called from a shell script?

I am *not* looking for how to *capture* stdout/stderr. I know how to do that; it involves some moderately messy multithreaded code, and a delay before the resulting output can be dumped to the console. I'm hoping instead that there is a simple way to tell the relevant machinery to just leave stdout/stderr alone to output to console as they normally would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`redirectOutput`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput(java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect)) for stdout, and the similar call `redirectError` for stderr:

```
builder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
builder.redirectError(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
```

As [@Abra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2164365/abra) points out, the [`inheritIO()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO()) method is a convenience for these two calls as well as the stdin equivalent.

Comment: Or you can simply call method [inheritIO](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO()) of class `java.lang.ProcessBuilder`

Comment: @Abra I overlooked that one! Great callout.